# How to define a module that is different from its filename?

Tags: requirejs

I am running into a strange error. **EDIT** Happens in Firefox, but not Chrome

In my HTML page I have this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">              
          require(['blah']);
    </script>
```

In a javascript file named someFileNameNotNamedBlah.js I have this:

```
define(
    'blah',
    ['jquery', 'amplify', 'config' ],
    function ($, amplify, config) {
    ...
});
```

The browser seems to be looking for blah.js... Why?  How do I fix this?

[Firebug looking for a filename that is not there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Sek.png)

Comment: The simple way to fix it is to either have a module called `blah` or remove the reference to it. Why are you using a dependency that doesn't exist?

Comment: @SimonSmith - I noticed it only happens in firefox, chrome can find it.

Answer (score 0):

The question you need to ask yourself is this: Given that RequireJS loads modules asynchronously via a XHR request, how **could** it know to look for the module `blah` in a file called `someFileNameNotNamedBlah.js` unless it's told where it lives?

You should define an alias for the module in your [`paths`](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths) configuration:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        blah: 'someFileNameNotNamedBlah'
    }
});
```

You can then remove the module name from your module:

```
define(['jquery', 'amplify', 'config' ], function ($, amplify, config) {
    //...
});
```

And find it by the alias:

```
require(['blah']);
```

Comment: The way it appears to work--at least in chrome--is that as long as there is a define("blah",[],...) that gets run, and a require(["blah"]) that gets run, it doesn't matter what the file name is or at least require can figure all that out.

Comment: That only works if that define('blah', ...) is executed before the require(['blah']) call is hit. So, best to add the paths to make sure any load race conditions are avoided.